# Touch on UIButton in a UITableViewCell cannot scroll the table

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I need to have a `UIButton` inside a `UITableViewCell`, everything works fine except when I touch inside the button and move my finger, the table does not scroll.

I tried to subclass `UIButton` and in touchesMoved: method send the same message to `self.nextResponder`, or call touchesCancelled and hope it will pass the touch event to next responder, they both do not work.

Is there any good way to solve this problem? Currently I am adding a `UIView` on top of the `UITableViewCell`, and detecting touch events manually, passing result to the button or the rest of the cell respectively, but this is a little bit dirty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can try is setting the **`delaysContentTouches`** property of the `UITableView` to **`YES`**.

Additionally you can set the **`canCancelContentTouches`** to **`YES`**.

> If the value of this property is NO, the scroll view does not scroll
>   regardless of finger movement once the content view starts tracking.

Source: [UIScrollView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/canCancelContentTouches)

Try:

```
_yourTableView.delaysContentTouches = YES;
_yourTableView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
```

Answer (score -4):

The best way is to make a custom cell and do your work neatly.

Check the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7)

Comment: This is just a link to documentation. It does not provide any feedback or a hint.

Comment: @reecon :  one suggestion : Just read the doc,You will understand why it was made the answer

Comment: I read it. I read also all linked documents. There is nothing about putting a UIButton in UITableViewCell.