# Touch Down/Up and Scroll in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm having a bit of of a pain point in figuring something out.

I have a uitableviewcontroller, and each cell is static. Inside each cell is a textbox. When the user TAPS on a textbox, I'd like an event to fire.

So while I'd like my table to still scroll, i'd also like tap events to work when you tape the textbox.

Apparently in uitableviews, they add a delay to your tap so you have to hold your finger down for a second or so for 'tap' to register. I felt this was not intuitive to a user, so I did this to fix it:

```
for subview in self.tableView.subviews as [UIView]
    {
        if subview is UIScrollView
        {
            let scroll = subview as UIScrollView
            scroll.delaysContentTouches = false
            break
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly, and now when I tap my textbox, it instantly executes my tap event! The problem now, however, is some of my textboxes are positioned right where a user would naturally scroll. When they put their finger down (touch down event) to scroll, it's unfortunately being intercepted by the tap event, and prevents scrolling and instead executes my event.

What i'd really want is if the user puts their finger down, and then swipes, it doesn't execute the touch down event. I thought to be clever and switch touch down to touch up, but when I put my finger down and then pick it back up, it does nothing (touch up inside seems to do nothing). I read this was because it only works on buttons and things like that, and not textfields. So, yes, now I can scroll without my action, but when I tap the textbox and lift my finger up it doesn't execute that, either.

Any ideas on how to either

1) permit touch downs and scrolling to co-exist without having to hold my finger down for a second and deal with that delayContentTouches?

2) somehow get a tap up inside event to fire when I tap on a textbox?

I saw some info here but didn't seem to help much: 
[UIButton inside UITableViewCell steals touch from UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965663/uibutton-inside-uitableviewcell-steals-touch-from-uitableview)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as luck would have it, I was able to figure this out. Would love some criticism/advice if something might not be ideal here, but what I did was add this to my subclassed textfield:

```
 override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
     performMyFunctionHere()
    return false
  }
```

So I am returning false on first responder which prevents any sort of keyboard appearing (which is what I wanted) and instead using performMyFunctionHere() I can do what I wanted to do (in my case, make an action sheet picker appear). I assign the action sheet picker in my view controller and assign it to each specific instance of my subclassed uitextfield. Nothing really complicated, to be honest. I'm surprised this works as well as it does.

By the way one thing that didn't seem extremely important was setting the delaysContentTouches as I mentioned above. I guess because now it's using the responder it will always work? It didn't seem to matter whether I removed it or not, but would love thoughts on whether it's better to leave it in or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want a textbox that can't be edited? Seems like what you want is a button instead or maybe even the whole cell being clickable. The delay from delaysContentTouches isn't anything near a second and you probably don't want to be messing with this.